# solidity contract state variable value show strange when invoke from external contrace

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, contract

### Description

Contract A has a state variable `owner` , which initialized well to `msg.sender`.
But this `owner` variable became `0x0` when invoked from another contract function which take address of contract A's instance and convert to A type.

### Environment

- Compiler version: 0.4.25
- Framework/IDE:  Remix
- EVM execution environment :
  Choose 'Javascript vm' on Run tab of Remix IDE;

### Steps to Reproduce: step is described among the code.

(code also available at https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/5210)

```
pragma solidity 0.4.25;

contract A{ 

   address public owner;

   event Ret(string flag, address sender, address owner);
      event ConstrutEvt(string flag,  address owner );

   function A() public{
       owner = msg.sender;
       emit ConstrutEvt("A", msg.sender);
   }

   function doSomething()  public view returns(string flag, address sender, address owner){
            emit Ret("A::doSomething", msg.sender, owner);
            return ("A::doSomething", msg.sender, owner);
   }
}

contract EvilDoer{
// step1: deploy contract A on remix IDE. 
// and the log show `owner` is a valid address value.

// step2: deploy contract EvilDoer.

// step3: on remix IDE run tab, invoke doSomething() use the contract A address as argument.  
// This time the log show that 'owner' is zero. Why ?

    function doSomethingEvil(address instanceAddrOfA) public {
         A contractA = A(instanceAddrOfA);
         contractA.doSomething();  
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is not with `EvilDoer`, but rather with the `doSomething()` function in `A`.

When you set your return values, you are assigning them values `string flag, address sender, address owner`. While this is a valid action, what you are inadvertently doing is overwriting the `owner` variable you defined above.

To fix this, change the name of `owner` in your return declaration to something like `_owner` so that you do not overwrite the global variable.

Comment: Thanks，you save me, although this is just a home exercise. It really a pitfall, and i think there many pitfalls when using solidity and many programmer may run into.

Comment: Soliity is so strange from mainstream programming language and i just don't like of it.